# JSON in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

I have a problem with json.
I have to do query:

`{
"method": "authorize",
"params": [
"100000202",
"TestApp677"
]
}`

To endpoint:http://xzasddfe.com/authorize/?ver=2_01

How to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to send or receive data from URL?

Comment: Use `NSJSONSerialization` ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). For the request you could use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: A simple JSON query like that you can easily assemble yourself, without even using a JSON kit.  What is your bottleneck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take a look at some JSON libraries. I prefer [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/) , as it`s really easy to use.

Next select a method to post data to your endpoint ( NSURLConnection , ASIHTTPRequest).

Here is an example using JSONKit and NSURLConnection:

```
-(void) postData {
   NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xzasddfe.com/authorize/?ver=2_01"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dic setValue:@"authorize" forKey:@"method"];
    [dic setVObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"100000202",@"TestApp677",nil] forKey:@"params"];

    NSString *jsonString=[dic JSONString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    [request release];

}
```